# Java regex for special character

Tags: java, regex

I have simple method for extract `#hashTag` from text:

```
private String[] buildHashTag(String str) {
        ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(#\\w+)\\b").matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            allMatches.add(m.group());
        }
        return allMatches.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

The problem is if i send string with special character, for example string "POMERANČ".

Test:
INPUT:

```
#Orange in Czech language mean #pomeranč :-)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[#Orange]
```

But it is FAIL, output must be `[#Orange, #pomeranč]`. Can you tell me, where is the wrong code? Help me. Thank you.

Comment: Add the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier or use `Pattern.compile("(?U)(#\\w+)\\b")`. Otherwise, `\b`/`\w` does not work properly.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you. It work.

Answer (score 5):

Add the [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) modifier or use `Pattern.compile("(?U)(#\\w+)\\b")`. Otherwise, `\b` and `\w` do not match all Unicode characters.

> When this flag is specified then the (US-ASCII only) *Predefined character classes* and *POSIX character classes* are in conformance with [Unicode Technical Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) Annex C: Compatibility Properties.

Here is [a demo](http://ideone.com/J8vQ7n):

```
String str = "#Orange in Czech language mean #pomeranč :-)";
ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?U)(#\\w+)\\b").matcher(str);
//                           ^^^^
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allMatches.toArray()));
```

Output: `[#Orange, #pomeranč]`

Comment: Does it work for you? Should I need to add more explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Use negated character class instead

```
/#[^ ]+/
```

- `[^ ]+` Negated character class, matches anything other than a space, which will in effect match characters till the next space

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cA0wS6/1)